# Webscraping a tricky asp.net page

Tags: asp.net, curl, web-scraping, mechanize

The overall goal is to perform a search on the following webpage http://www.cma-cgm.com/eBusiness/Tracking/Default.aspx with a container value of CMAU1173561. I have tried two approaches, the php extension cURL and python's mechanized.  The php approached involves a performing a POST submit using the input fields found on the page (NOTE: These are really ugly on the asp.net page). The returned page does not contain any of the search results. The second approaches involves using python's mechanize module. In this approach I load the page, select the form, then change the text field ctl00$ContentPlaceBody$TextSearch to the container value. When I load the response again no search results.

I am at a really dead end. Any help would be appreciate because as it stands my next step is to become a asp.net expertm which i perfer not to.

Comment: When you made the PHP cURL request did you send the hidden  __VSTATE parameter? The web server requires this to validate the other form data.

Answer (score 0):

The source of that page is pretty scary (giant viewstate, tables all over the place, inline CSS, styles that look like they were copied from Word).

Regardless...an ASP.Net form still passes the same raw data to the server as any other form (though it is abstracted to the developer).

It's very possible that you are missing the cookies which go along with the request. If the search page (or any piece of the site) uses session state, the ASP.Net session cookie must be included in the request. You will be able to tell it from its name (contains "asp.net" and "session").

I assume that you have used a tool like Firebug or Chrome to view the complete outgoing request when the page is submitted. From my quick test, it looks like the request may be performed with a GET, not a POST. I submitted a form, looked at the request, and pasted the URL into a new browser window.

Example: `http://www.cma-cgm.com/eBusiness/Tracking/Default.aspx?ContNum=CMAU1173561&T=57201202648`

This may be all you need to do.

Comment: A GET response does not return any of the shipping information. 
As for cookies I have tried using both twill and mechanize in python. Both handle cookies automatically so I don't believe that to be the problem. 
Working code would really be appreciated because there seems to be a big gap between the theory and actually getting the application working.